# Can I use Boost and/or C++ libraries SAFELY inside an Apache module?

Tags: c++, apache, boost, apache-modules

In my Apache module, which is built in C++, I uses strings, vectors, and the related when attempting to provide functionality to my module.

My concern is that I am not using the Apache memory pool and that the program is going to segfault along the way, but at the same time I having difficulty with certain task such as this:

```
static void parseSTR(char *input, const char *sep, int &count, apr_table_t *&values, apr_pool_t *mp)
{
    char *part, *next;

    if (isStrNull(input)) 
        return;

    count = 1;

    part = apr_strtok(input, sep, &next);

    while (part) {
        apr_table_set(values, apr_itoa(mp, count), part);

        part = apr_strtok(NULL, sep, &next);

        count++;
    }
}
```

which I am using a delimited string parser to parse URLs and domain names. Surely there is a more efficient way to provide this functionality. I am using the apr_table structure to contain each part, I know I could use an apr_array_header, but....

So I would like to know:

1. Could I use Boost to provide the missing functionality SAFELY?
2. Will I run into memory clashes because I am not using the pool memory?
3. For string, vector, and etc that free their own memory, is this a problem laying in wait?

I did search for this issue, but the other issues do not seem to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Boost should be safe, it depends on the specific *parts* you're using though to make any definite calls on its safety.

As for memory management, you could write your own implementation of std::allocator that uses Apache/APR's memory allocation. You can then pass this allocator as a template argument to the STL containers you're using (*usually* the second template argument).

As for Boost's smart-pointers (if you're using them), they can (on construction) be given a function-pointer as parameter that implements memory-deallocation (as a replacement for `delete`).

E.g. an allocator like this could do the trick for you:

```
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class apr_allocator
{
    public:
        typedef size_t    size_type;
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef T*        pointer;
        typedef const T*  const_pointer;
        typedef T&        reference;
        typedef const T&  const_reference;
        typedef T         value_type;

        template<typename U>
        struct rebind
        { typedef apr_allocator<U> other; };

        pointer allocate(size_type n, const void* = 0)
        {
            pointer new_mem = apr_do_whatever_is_necessary_to_allocate(n * sizeof(value_type));
            if (!new_mem)
                throw std::bad_alloc();
            return new_mem;
        }

        void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
        {
            apr_release_memory(p, n);
        }

        pointer address(reference r) const
        {
            return &r;
        }

        const_pointer address(const_reference r) const
        {
            return &r;
        }

        size_type max_size() const
        {
            // Largest amount of elements T that can meaningfully be allocated
            return 1337;
        }

        void construct(pointer p, const_reference val)
        {
            new ((void *)p) value_type(val);
        }

        void destroy(pointer p)
        {
            p->~T();
        }
};

template <typename T>
inline bool operator==(const apr_allocator<T>& a, const new_allocator<T>& b)
{
    if (&a == &b)
        return true;
    if (/* a can deallocate elements created with b and vice-versa */)
        return true;
    return false;
}

template <typename T>
inline bool operator!=(const apr_allocator<T>& a, const apr_allocator<T>& b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

Also note that if your allocator requires internal state (e.g. a reference to a specific memory-pool) you *must* ensure that the allocator is copy-constructable. Also it *must* be default constructible (though you can pass a pre-constructed instance as parameter to STL containers' constructors).

Answer (score 0):

We are using C++ and Boost heavily in Apache on Windows and we do not see any problems related to our use of `new` or similar C++isms.